# Connecting bs-buttons in a bs-form to component actions (ember-bootstrap)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ember.js, ember-bootstrap

What is the correct way of connecting a `bs-button` inside a `bs-form` to a component action?

---

Some background on what I want to do and have already tried:

I'm in the process of upgrading Ember from 2.10 to 2.14 and ember-bootstrap from 0.11.3 to 1.0. I encountered a problem with ember-bootstrap.

I have two buttons in a form (`bs-form`): "Save" and "Cancel".
The form is hosted in an Ember component. In the old version I just had two `bs-button` elements, like this:

```
{{bs-button defaultText="Save" type="primary" action="save"}}
{{bs-button defaultText="Cancel" type="primary" action="cancel"}}
```

In the component class, I defined the matching action:

```
actions: {
  save() { /* do saving stuff */ }
  cancel() { /* do cancelling stuff */ }
}
```

Now this no longer works: `bs-button` uses `onClick` instead of `action` now, but just adding `onClick="save"` does not work (I get `TypeError: action is not a function`); also, `onClick=(action "save")` does not work (`Assertion Failed: An action named 'save' was not found in (generated edit-organization controller)`).

However, when not using `bs-button` but a normal `button` element in conjunction with the `action` helper, it works just fine:

```
<button class="btn btn-default" {{action 'cancel'}}>Cancel</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" {{action 'save'}}>Save</button>
```

I suspect the problem is related to using a *component* to host the form; after all, the ember-bootstrap docs state that actions are used to...

> send an action to your controller.

Still I'd like to use a component (after all, controllers are going away, right?). Any help on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create closure action and pass it to bs-button component.

```
{{bs-button defaultText="Save" type="primary" save=(action "save")}}
{{bs-button defaultText="Cancel" type="primary" cancel=(action "cancel")}}
```

Inside the component,

```
<button class="btn btn-default" {{action cancel}}>Cancel</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" {{action save}}>Save</button>
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, your explanation is about how to fix the bs-button component. But bs-button is not my component, but it's part of the ember-bootstrap addon; so what I'm looking for is how to correctly use this addon, not how to write the functionality myself.

Comment: Oh Sorry. Now I understood your problem. I believe you need to define action is controller, that's the breaking change introduced in [1.0.0 alpha releases](https://github.com/kaliber5/ember-bootstrap/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#100-alpha3-2017-01-21) . To adhere DDAU principle. I haven't used this. you can confirm this from author @simonihmig  who will be active in ember slack community